# Can't pass value from a button into timer function

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to pass the variable time from the `easy_click` into the `RunTimer_tick`. This is what I have done, but it doesn't work:

```cs
public void RunTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e, int time )
{
    RunTimer.Interval = time;
    target();
}

private void Target_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    scoring();
}

public int easy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int time = 2000;
    return time;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the full code, and perhaps an image of your form?

Comment: How do you add these **events** Mr. Lewis? and why are changing their signatures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the signature of the timer tick method. You have to stick with the signature expected by the timer, and that's without the additional `int time` argument.

The same applies for the button click event handler. The event handler expects a given signature and you must not change it, so you can't change the return value to `int`.

If I get the intent of the code right, you just want to change the timer interval when clicking the "easy" button. This could be written like so:

```
public void easy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RunTimer.Interval = 2000;
}
```

You would then remove the `time` parameter from the timer's tick method:

```
public void RunTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    target();
}
```